# python extracting sequences from gene prediction output

Tags: python, extract, prediction, sequences, fasta

I've done a gene prediction using SoftBerry and it returns output like this:

Predicted protein(s):

```
>FGENESH:[mRNA]   1  12 exon (s)   4267  -   6782  1296 bp, chain +
ATGATACGCACTGCGCTTTCACGAGCAGCGGCCATCGTCGCCGCCCGCACCTCCGCCAAG
CTCCGCCCTTCCCTCCTCGCTCGATCTCCGCCGTCCAGACTCCTCCACGATGGGATTAAC
GCCAACCCAGTTGCTCTTCAGATGATCAACTACGCCGTCTCTCTCGCCAGGTCTCAGAAA
>FGENESH:   1  12 exon (s)   4267  -   6782   431 aa, chain +
MIRTALSRAAAIVAARTSAKLRPSLLARSPPSRLLHDGINANPVALQMINYAVSLARSQK
SDESYGQAQLVLEQCLSSQPSEGQDLATHNSRAMVLMAMSTLLSERGKLDEAIEKLQKVE
```

etc: an extensive output so manual editing is not trivial.
I need to fish out the sequences that start with '>FGENESH:[mRNA]'. So, I try this:

```
for line in infile:
    if line.startswith('>FGENESH:[mRNA]'):
        print(line)
        outfile.write(line)
```

Which gives me only the header lines:

```
>FGENESH:[mRNA]   1  12 exon (s)   4267  -   6782  1296 bp, chain +
```

However, I would like the output to look like this:

```
>FGENESH:[mRNA]   1  12 exon (s)   4267  -   6782  1296 bp, chain +
ATGATACGCACTGCGCTTTCACGAGCAGCGGCCATCGTCGCCGCCCGCACCTCCGCCAAG
CTCCGCCCTTCCCTCCTCGCTCGATCTCCGCCGTCCAGACTCCTCCACGATGGGATTAAC
GCCAACCCAGTTGCTCTTCAGATGATCAACTACGCCGTCTCTCTCGCCAGGTCTCAGAAA
```

Could anyone advice me how to obtain that?
I would be much obliged - being a novice and all.
Thank you.

jd

Comment: There should be '>' in front of the sequence headers, but somehow I was not allowed to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
flag = False

for line in infile:
    if flag is True:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            flag = False
        else:
            outfile.write(line)
    if line.startswith('>FGENESH:[mRNA]'):
        flag = True
        outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your gene output is in standard FASTA format, which any bioinformatics package will be able to read accurately; using such modules will improve versatility downstream.  For example, the BioPython module (http://biopython.org/wiki/Biopython) will let you extract the mRNA sequences:

```
from Bio import SeqIO 
from StringIO import StringIO

output = []

input = """>FGENESH:[mRNA]   1  12 exon (s)   4267  -   6782  1296 bp, chain +
ATGATACGCACTGCGCTTTCACGAGCAGCGGCCATCGTCGCCGCCCGCACCTCCGCCAAG
CTCCGCCCTTCCCTCCTCGCTCGATCTCCGCCGTCCAGACTCCTCCACGATGGGATTAAC
GCCAACCCAGTTGCTCTTCAGATGATCAACTACGCCGTCTCTCTCGCCAGGTCTCAGAAA
>FGENESH:   1  12 exon (s)   4267  -   6782   431 aa, chain +
MIRTALSRAAAIVAARTSAKLRPSLLARSPPSRLLHDGINANPVALQMINYAVSLARSQK
SDESYGQAQLVLEQCLSSQPSEGQDLATHNSRAMVLMAMSTLLSERGKLDEAIEKLQKVE"""

for record in SeqIO.parse(StringIO(input), 'fasta'):
    if "FGENESH:[mRNA]" in record.description:
        output.append(record)

print output[0].format('fasta')
```

Output:

```
>FGENESH:[mRNA]  1 12 exon (s)  4267 -  6782 1296 bp, chain +
ATGATACGCACTGCGCTTTCACGAGCAGCGGCCATCGTCGCCGCCCGCACCTCCGCCAAG
CTCCGCCCTTCCCTCCTCGCTCGATCTCCGCCGTCCAGACTCCTCCACGATGGGATTAAC
GCCAACCCAGTTGCTCTTCAGATGATCAACTACGCCGTCTCTCTCGCCAGGTCTCAGAAA
```

But then you can easily do much more with the sequences afterward, like translate them:

```
print output[0].seq.translate()
```

MIRTALSRAAAIVAARTSAKLRPSLLARSPPSRLLHDGINANPVALQMINYAVSLARSQK

Or efficiently write them to file:

```
with open("fgene.fasta", "w") as f:
    SeqIO.write(output, f, "fasta")
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a regex based solution:

```
import re

data = '''>FGENESH:[mRNA]   1  12 exon (s)   4267  -   6782  1296 bp, chain +
ATGATACGCACTGCGCTTTCACGAGCAGCGGCCATCGTCGCCGCCCGCACCTCCGCCAAG
CTCCGCCCTTCCCTCCTCGCTCGATCTCCGCCGTCCAGACTCCTCCACGATGGGATTAAC
GCCAACCCAGTTGCTCTTCAGATGATCAACTACGCCGTCTCTCTCGCCAGGTCTCAGAAA
>FGENESH:   1  12 exon (s)   4267  -   6782   431 aa, chain +
MIRTALSRAAAIVAARTSAKLRPSLLARSPPSRLLHDGINANPVALQMINYAVSLARSQK
SDESYGQAQLVLEQCLSSQPSEGQDLATHNSRAMVLMAMSTLLSERGKLDEAIEKLQKVE
>FGENESH:[mRNA]   1  12 exon (s)   4267  -   6782  1296 bp, chain +
ATGATACGCACTGCGCTTTCACGAGCAGCGGCCATCGTCGCCGCCCGCACCTCCGCCAAG
CTCCGCCCTTCCCTCCTCGCTCGATCTCCGCCGTCCAGACTCCTCCACGATGGGATTAAC
GCCAACCCAGTTGCTCTTCAGATGATCAACTACGCCGTCTCTCTCGCCAGGTCTCAGAAA'''

pattern = re.compile(r'^(>FGENESH:\[mRNA\].*?[ACTG\n]+)$', re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
for match in pattern.findall(data):
    print match
```

Output:

```
>FGENESH:[mRNA]   1  12 exon (s)   4267  -   6782  1296 bp, chain +
ATGATACGCACTGCGCTTTCACGAGCAGCGGCCATCGTCGCCGCCCGCACCTCCGCCAAG
CTCCGCCCTTCCCTCCTCGCTCGATCTCCGCCGTCCAGACTCCTCCACGATGGGATTAAC
GCCAACCCAGTTGCTCTTCAGATGATCAACTACGCCGTCTCTCTCGCCAGGTCTCAGAAA
>FGENESH:[mRNA]   1  12 exon (s)   4267  -   6782  1296 bp, chain +
ATGATACGCACTGCGCTTTCACGAGCAGCGGCCATCGTCGCCGCCCGCACCTCCGCCAAG
CTCCGCCCTTCCCTCCTCGCTCGATCTCCGCCGTCCAGACTCCTCCACGATGGGATTAAC
GCCAACCCAGTTGCTCTTCAGATGATCAACTACGCCGTCTCTCTCGCCAGGTCTCAGAAA
```

Comment: Alternate pattern - ```r'^(>FGENESH:\[mRNA\][^>]*)'```

Comment: @wwii: that assumes that all lines begin with `>` which might, or might not, be true - the OP didn't say. `[ACTG\n]+` assures that a contiguous run of base sequences (and new lines) will be matched (that might also be an invalid assumption - I don't know).

Comment: It's FASTA format, the default for sequence information, so unless there's some really, really weird stuff going on all the header lines will begin with ">" and none of the other lines will.